# Puppeteer - strange PDF header and footer behaviour

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Headers and footers appear to be broken for me in Puppeteer when generating PDFs. If a footer but no header is set, then the current date and time will be displayed at the very top of the page (where the header should be), regardless of what the actual content of `headerTemplate` is. When a header but no footer is set, then the PDF will display `about:blank` and `1/1` at the bottom of the page (where the footer should be), again, regardless of what the actual `headerTemplate` value is.

If both `footerTemplate` and `headerTemplate` are set, then nothing will be displayed. I have not worked with Puppeteer in some time but my setup used to work. However I did upgrade Puppeteer and skipped quite a few versions. I was originally at some minor version of version `9` and now I am using `19.8.5`.

Have there been any changes that require me to adjust my code or is this just a bug? The code which can be used to reproduce the error is the following:

```
const { writeFile } = require('fs/promises');
const { launch } = require('puppeteer');

const puppeteerOptions = {
    margin: { top: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100, right: 100 },
    format: 'a4',
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    // comment these two in and out for the described behaviour
    headerTemplate: '<div class="pageNumber"></div>',
    footerTemplate: '<div class="pageNumber"></div>',
};

async function main() {
    const browser = await launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
        headless: true,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent('<div>Hello, World!</div>', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

    const pdf = await page.pdf(puppeteerOptions);

    await browser.close();

    writeFile('./output.pdf', pdf);
}

main();
```

This is the output when there is a `footerTemplate` set:
[image: footer]

and this is the bottom of the page when a `headerTemplate` is set:
[image: header]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then my issue might have something to do with the borderlessness of the PDF? How would I control that, are the provided margins not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `font-size` is a required style property for header and footer.

```
<div style="font-size: 12px;" class="pageNumber"></div>
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I found using a system font is required, setting another font-size is prohibited and using relative dimensions is useless.